# Abstract user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, polymorphism, abstract

I am fairly new to WPF MVVM.

I have a user control named MyButtonsView which inherits from UserControl. This user control should display two other user controls.

I have few viewmodel classes:
MyRedButtonViewModel, MyBlueButtonViewModel.
They both derive from an abstract class named MyAbsButtonViewModel. This abstract view model enforces all derive view models to implement a property name GetImage.

In the XAML of MyButtonsView, I have a grid that should have two rows. In the first row I want to have MyRedButtonViewModel, in the second row I want to have MyBlueButtonViewModel. Both should display an image inside a button which is binded to GetImage property. (It is polymorphic).

How can I tell the XAML to load the right viewmodel for each row?

is there a proper way to implement it. I am mind opened to change my design.

Comment: Besides your question: Rethink about your naming. MyAbsButtonViewModel is quite confusing because Abs is usually used for the mathematical absolute value. A better name is MyAbstractButtonViewModel, as far as these additional character won't hurt you but improve code quality. Another suggestion is ButtonViewModelBase to indicate that it is a base class other classes can derive from.

Answer (score 1):

You can define use different ViewModel as DataContext for the two buttons.

MyButtonsView binding to MyButtonsViewModel, MyButtonsViewModel has two properties MyBlueButtonViewModel and MyRedButtonViewModel.

In the MyButtonsView you can define somethings like this:

```
<MyRedButton DataContext = "MyRedButtonViewModel" ..../>
<MyBlueButton DataContext = "MyBlueButtonViewModel" .../>
```